# In Support Vector Machine, why is the distance from the origin to the decision boundary b / ||w||

Tags: machine-learning

In the picture of [SVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhYFV.png) from Wikipedia, at the lower left corner - pointed by the red arrow, the distance from the (0,0) to the decision boundary is b / ||w||. Why is that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may explain it.  Note:  it seems that the picture from Wikipedia should more correctly show a dot product instead of a star I think.  I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This is very clear. Thank you so much!